# LoadControl, usercontrol in WebMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, webmethod

I am trying to send an email through a `WebMethod`  Below is the code I typically use on a regular post back

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SendEmail(string name, string phone, string emailaddress, string interest, string comments)
{
    var control = LoadControl("~/Shared/Controls/EmailTemplate_PartnerWithUs.ascx");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    Html32TextWriter htw = new Html32TextWriter(sw);

    control.RenderControl(htw);

    sb.Replace("%name%", name);
    sb.Replace("%phone%", phone);
    sb.Replace("%emailaddress%", emailaddress);
    sb.Replace("%interest%", interest);
    sb.Replace("%comments%", comments);
    EmailUtility.SendEmailMessage(SettingsManager.GetContactRecipientEmails(), "CoyleHomeBuyers.com Partner Form", sb.ToString());
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(string)'
```

Is there a way to load this control within the WebMethod?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UserControl uc= new UserControl();
Control control = uc.LoadControl("~/Shared/Controls/EmailTemplate_PartnerWithUs.ascx");
```

Comment: perfect, I had done it once before but couldn't find it, knew it was pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it into a control type.

For example:

```
Email_PartnerWithUs control = (Email_PartnerWithUs)LoadControl("~/Shared/Controls/EmailTemplate_PartnerWithUs.ascx");
```

See here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.loadcontrol(v=VS.71).aspx